# Get url param in React using TypeScript and HashRouter

Tags: typescript, react-router

I am using React with Typescript.

I want to get the param named planId from url. I know some guys can get params value using match object, but I do not know how to implement it in Typescript

Here is the sample url: https://example.com/page1.aspx#/yb5LFy1L4kyhc_NoBGmItZYAAb19

Thanks

```html
<HashRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={() => (<Groups context={this.props.context} spHttpClient={this.props.spHttpClient} />)} />
        <Route path="/:planId" render={() => (<PlanTimeline />)} />
        <Route render={() => <h1>Page Not found</h1>} />
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: I think this will work `this.props.match.params.planId`

Comment: Thank you. It should be better if you have sample code because I am a newbie in Typescript

Comment: In your `PlanTimeline` component you can use `this.props.match.params.planId` wherever you want. For example, `console.log(this.props.match.params.planId)` it will print in console. Or `const planId = this.props.match.params.planId` this will get the id in variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can get the `planId`